# How to set a tab background as transparent?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I need to add 5 tab bar images to a `Titanium.UI.tabGroup`, but I can't figure out how to achieve transparent background.

I've tried different properties when creating the tab group but nothing works:

```
  this.myTabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({
    opacity: 0, // NOT WORKING
    backgroundColor: 'transparent', // NOT WORKING
    barImage: null // NOT WORKING
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found the answer!

Using the following option solved the problem:

```
  this.myTabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({
    tabsBackgroundColor : 'transparent',
    includeOpaqueBars : true,
    translucent : false
  });
```